# php change array format for url

Tags: php, html, arrays, format

I have a weird project I'm working on. I'm totally new to php so it has been a struggle so far.

I have a form that gives an array and posts it:

```
...
return($keywords);
}

$keywordlist = explode("\r\n", $keywordlist);
foreach($keywordlist as $keyword){
print_r(mixer(strtolower($keyword)));
}
```

I get this:

```
Array ( [0] => one [1] => two [2] => three [3] => four [4] => five [5] => six [6] => ....
```

But would like it to come out like this instead:

```
%28one%2Ctwo%2Cthree%2Cfour%2Cfive%2Csix%29
```

Ultimately hope to be able to attach it to the end of a url like ask.com search:

```
"http://www.ask.com/web?q=(put my keywords here)"
```

then navigate there

In theory it would be like I typed "(one,two,three,four,five,six)" into the search bar and pressed enter.

Hopefully that makes some sense.

Comment: and use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function to encode special characters such as `&`, `?` and other characters to be used inside query strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
$keywords = array('one', 'two', 'three');
$query = '(' . implode(',', $keywords) . ')';
echo('Search query: ' . $query . PHP_EOL);
$query = rawurlencode($query);
echo('Encoded: ' . $query . PHP_EOL);
```

Gives this output:

> Search query: (one,two,three) Encoded:
>   %28one%2Ctwo%2Cthree%29

Answer (score 7):

Something like this:

```
$commaSeparated = implode(',', $array);
$withParens = '(' + $commaSeparated + ')';
$urlEncoded = urlencode($withParens);
print $urlEncoded;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the php [implode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function.

So you could do this:

```
$array = new array ( [0] => one [1] => two [2] => three [3] => four [4] => five [5] => six );
$string = '%28'.implode( '%2C', $array ).'%29';
```

Now `$string` will be what you need

Answer (score 2):

```
$keywordlist = explode("\r\n", $keywordlist);    
array_walk($keywordlist, 'strtolower');
$keywords = '('.implode(",", $keywordList).')';
```

Answer (score 2):

`print_r`is what prints your array like this.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

How to solve it depends on a few things. What does `mixer()`do? And is the keywords always in lowercase? If mixer doens't do much and the keywords are in lowercase you could do something like:

> $string = '%28' . implode('%2C',
>   $keyword) . '%29';

If it's URL encoding you are after you could use the function `url_encode` instead of manually adding encoded values as above.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
$input = array('one', 'two', 'three');
$s = implode(',', $input);
$s = '('.$i.')';
print urlencode($s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could encode each part of the array using urlencode and then manually put it in your url (making a url string by yourself). http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Or you could use this function instead: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php